# Using a list (of string) for looping items picture slideshow

Tags: vb.net, list, indexing, indexof

I've found a sample code to show some pictures originally was a slideshow... the problem is it only runs to the right... looping correctly starting again from the first picture but i can't find the inverse way to show the last picture if i press the left key... this is the working right code:

```
    Private Sub ShowNextImage()
    'From 0 to _ImageFileNames.Length, use Mod to repeat when past end.
    _CurrentImage = (_CurrentImage + 1)
    If _CurrentImage = _ImageFileNames.Count Then
        _CurrentImage = 0
    End If

    If Not Me.BackgroundImage Is Nothing Then
        DirectCast(Me.BackgroundImage, Image).Dispose()
    End If
    Me.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(_ImageFileNames(_CurrentImage))
End Sub
```

I've tried this but dont works:

```
Private Sub ShowPrevImage()
    'From 0 to _ImageFileNames.Length, use Mod to repeat when past end.
    _CurrentImage = (_CurrentImage - 1)
    If _CurrentImage = 0 Then 
        _CurrentImage = _ImageFileNames.Count
    End If

    If Not Me.BackgroundImage Is Nothing Then
        DirectCast(Me.BackgroundImage, Image).Dispose()
    End If
    Me.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(_ImageFileNames(_CurrentImage))
End Sub
```

it works fine to the right and to the left, except when the photo is the first one (don't goes to the last picture!).

Any help?

Comment: A count is 1-based. An index is 0-based. I’m sure you can figure it out from there.

Comment: @SamAxe 
SOLVED!!! i change again  `CurrentImage = 0 ` into  `CurrentImage = -1 ` and `CurrentImage = _ImageFileNames.Count  -1 `  now it works!! MANY THANKS

Comment: Please stop putting difficulty levels and language tags in your titles.  it is just noise that has nothing to do with the problem (and if they are "easy" you ought not be posting at all; do some research and debugging and fix it yourself).  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] and perhaps [How Much Research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: @arc95 Good job!  If you write up your answer (below) then you can accept it and the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change:
    CurrentImage = 0  into
    CurrentImage = -1
    and
    CurrentImage = _ImageFileNames.Count -1

now it works!!